# Remote UAC bypass and Microsoft does not regard it as security Boundry

Tags: windows, malware

Microsoft has tremendously increased the security of Windows 8.1 but i found a technique to bypass UAC remotely

1. I know that if User belongs to local group Administrators he is not given full Admin Token on the box nether locally or remotely
2. He is given filtered token and when he needs to perform admin related tasks he needs to pass UAC
3. This boundary keeps Malware from escalating on the Box
4. I found a way a remote user is given full admin Token and he is full Administrator on the box and in this he bypasses UAC
5. Though The user belongs to local group Administrators not default administrator he bypasses uac Can this be regarded Privilege Escalation
6. I know about Tokens Primary Token, Filtered Token, Impersonation Token Etc I did full experiment with this and it works, why doesn't Microsoft care

The Technique

Enable print and file sharing on target computer
set LocalAccountTokenFilterpolicy to 1 in registry on target computer ( i was only forced to change registry in some windows 7 professional machine) in in windows 8.1 0r Ultimate i did not touched registry.so changing Registry is not Mandatory

suppose the ip of target computer is 10.0.0.5
use this command for the hack
*\\10.0.0.5\Admin$\system32\Services.msc* hit enter or ok in the run prompt
when service app loads from remote machine
use this command go to Help > Print Topic > Print > Find printer and then use this command in the explorer bar  *\\10.0.0.5\Admin$\system32\cmd.exe*  hit enter
you will get CMD as Administrator without UAC
Here service app already loads with elevated Token and i.e is why cmd loads as administrator, Please first Understand the importance of remote UAC bypass and then comment

Comment: let me see if I got this right: you disabled UAC restrictions for remote logins by changing the registry key "LocalAccountTokenFilterpolicy" and then you're complaining that process token elevation is no longer enforced ?

Comment: @Stephane don't get too excited the use of registry is not mandatory in my case as 8.1 and windows 7 ultimate did not use "LocalAccountTokenFilterpolicy" and in case my attack machine was XP it was even more easier, however some windows 7 professional versions forced me to change registry and you should test this yourself

Comment: @raven for the record (relating to your comments elsewhere) it is not "the mods" downvoting your questions, it is the community as a whole - because they were not good questions. Likewise, if your questions get closed, it is not because we don't like your SUPERHACK, again it is because it is not a good question, that fits well on our site. Please take a few minutes to take the [tour], and peruse the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Inconsistency in the need for Registry alterations sounds like bad change management and testing procedures to me. Re-build a box fresh, jack UAC up to full power, and try again. Chances are, you'll figure out that you'd already disabled UAC on one of your earlier test systems and just forgotten about it.

Comment: Or, equally likely, didnt realize that he already approved the UAC prompt when he opened MMC.exe in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you Understand that Changing  LocalAccountTokenFilterpolicy does not allow us to bypass UAC it allows other accounts that belong to Local group Administartors to access hidden administrative shares in registry and in no way allows us to bypass UAC or Remote UAC in 8.1

Comment: The above method can be used to locally bypass uac and when we bypass it locally or remotely we have write access to program files folder

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, Microsoft does not care because you followed their directions to disable UAC in order to 'bypass' their UAC.

> **To disable UAC remote restrictions, follow these steps:**
>  1.Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
>   
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>      
>  
> 3. If the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry entry does not exist, follow these steps:
>           
> a. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>           
> b. Type LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then press ENTER. 
>      
>  **4. Right-click LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then click Modify.
>       
> 5. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.**
>      
>  6. Exit Registry Editor.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016

Comment: ya you can diable UAC but while disabling the UAC you have to pass UAC i.e you have to say yes to a UAC prompt wile when i bypass it i don't encounter UAC, I straightaway get full Admin Token

Comment: I'm just saying if Microsoft already said it's not a vulnerability, then I don't see why the mods would consider it one.

Comment: Changing Registry is not Mandotory and setting LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy in registry does not IN ANYWAY allows us to bypass uac, you will still get UAC prompts for Admin related Tasks,please UNderstand it First,please test it first

Comment: When you start the registry by regedit or any other means, does it prompt from UAC?